# Server migration dns doesn't resolve

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I have a problem migrating accounts from one server (SERVER_1) to another new (SERVER_2).

I have a domain DOMAIN_1 with some NS created on the domain provider (CDmon):
ns.DOMAIN_1 pointing to SERVER_1.
ns2.DOMAIN_1 pointing to SERVER_1.
ns3.DOMAIN_1 pointing to SERVER_2. 
ns4.DOMAIN_1 pointing to SERVER_2.

All infraestructure of SERVER_1 and their ns works fine.

DOMAIN_1 is hosted on SERVER_1 and points ns.DOMAIN_1 and ns2.DOMAIN_1. In SERVER_1 in DOMAIN_1 DNS zone I have one A entry for every ns (ns, ns2, ns3, ns4) everyone pointing to their respective server IP.

In SERVER_2 I have a zones created for ns3.DOMAIN_1 and it works (ping works, and if i test in browsers it resolves fine).

The problem become when I set a DOMAIN_2 pointing to ns3.DOMAIN_1 and ns4.DOMAIN_1 (it is migrated from SERVER_1 where I created an A registers to SERVER_2 ip). After more than 24h this site doesn't respond (ping says unknown host, browser access doesn't work, ...). In SERVER_2 I have zones created like ns3.DOMAIN_1 (for ns3.DOMAIN_1 works fine):

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN  SOA     DOMAIN_2. root.DOMAIN_2. (
    2013042201  ;Serial
    3600        ;Refresh
    1800        ;Retry
    604800      ;Expire
    86400       ;Minimum TTL
)
            IN      NS              ns3.DOMAIN_1.
            IN      NS              ns4.DOMAIN_1.

*               IN      A               SERVER_2 ip
@               IN      A               SERVER_2 ip
www             IN      A               SERVER_2 ip
```

If I force SERVER_2 ip to DOMAIN_2 in hosts file it works fine...
I think that's all configurated well but seems a problem with NS or something similar...
I'm forgeting something? I'm doing something bad? :(

Thank you very much! And excuse me for my english

Comment: Troubleshooting DNS is far easier if you supply the real domain(s).

Comment: Check the logs on the name server.  Run dnslint on the zone files.  Try dig from the command line of the name server.  Try dig from a different server.  If you haven't found your answer yet, post the output of all of that and maybe we can help.

Comment: I founded the error... on named.conf I have allow-query { localhost; };  I changed it to allow-query { any; };. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the error... on named.conf I have

```
allow-query { localhost; };
```

I changed it to

```
allow-query { any; };
```